# Using the x-user-id in the c# forge package within the 2legged context

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge

We are trying to create a simple integration for a Forge App with BIM360, we have done loads of stuff using the 3 legged contexts but now we are trying to expose (some functionality) to users without the need for them to explicitly log into their Autodesk account.

All very exciting stuff!

We are making the following call within a 2 legged context as per the documentation (apiReferenc: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-hub_id-projects-GET/#headers , C# reference: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/ProjectsApi.md#gethubprojects)  and would like to add the x-user-id to this call

```
var api = await factory.CreateProjectsApiAsync(TwoLeggedToken);
var apiResult = await api.GetHubProjectsAsync(hubId);
```

The x-user-id is instrumental in filtering so the users are only able to see and access the hubs/projects they are added to. 
We, however, can't find how to implement this x-user-id in the c# forge package. The different c# forge package API's configuration have Username, UserAgent but no user id or similar properties. We also can't seem to find the type of user id the x-user-id header expects. Is this the full name of an Autodesk account (ex: "Samuel Middendorp"), the username specified in the Autodesk account settings. s.middendorpXXXX or the user id specified when looking at forge calls responses (for example createUserId).

I hope any of you fine people at Autodesk could help me out here!
I would also like to Thank Bryan Huang for quickly answering our previous questions about missing typings and more and helping us get to this point in development!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reporting. I have created an issue on our [forge-api-dotnet-client](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/issues/63) repository to our team to allocate time to add this support, please see:

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/issues/63

Answer (score 0):

In reference to your question about which id the `x-user-id` header requires, it is the `uid`.

If you have a two-legged token, you can retrieve this by searching for a user by email with the [BIM 360 API users/search endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/users-search-GET/):

`https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/:hubId/users/search?email=:userEmail`

Here's a sample response:

```
[
  {
    "id": "579d4408-39a4-4b3a-9474-6e781e68ab94",
    "account_id": "9dbb160e-b904-458b-bc5c-ed184687592d",
    "status": "pending",
    "role": "account_admin",
    "company_id": "14e95a5e-02eb-49aa-a39a-447d90544873",
    "company_name": "Autodesk",
    "email": "john.smith@mail.com",
    "name": "John Smith",
    "nickname": "Johnny",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "uid": "L9EBJKCGCXBB", // This is the one you want
    "image_url": "http://static-dc.autodesk.net/etc/designs/v201412151200/autodesk/adsk-design/images/autodesk_header_logo_140x23.png",
    "last_sign_in": null,
    "address_line_1": "The Fifth Avenue",
    "address_line_2": "#301",
    "city": "New York",
    "postal_code": "10011",
    "state_or_province": "New York",
    "country": "United States",
    "phone": "(634)329-2353",
    "company": "Autodesk",
    "job_title": "Software Developer",
    "industry": "IT",
    "about_me": "Nothing here",
    "created_at": "2015-04-29T06:59:05.582Z",
    "updated_at": "2015-04-29T06:59:05.582Z"
  }
]
```