# Is 3-Legged authentication required for uploading a file to BIM360/ACC

Tags: autodesk-bim360, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-construction-cloud

I am going through this [step-by-step guide on uploading a file to BIM360](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/document-management/upload-document-s3/) . I was wondering why, at the beginning, it says *"Acquire 3-LeggedAuthentication"* since all of the endpoints throughout are *"user context optional"* ?

Is it possible to use 2-Legged authentication?

Comment: Is it worth you defining what X-legged authentication means? The question is already rather brief, and I wonder if this phrase will make things more confusing. Is this a REST API?

Comment: This is a basic authentication differentiation with BIM360/ACC - whether it's a server side app or a user facing app -  have a look here. https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/overview/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**
The short answer - a 3-legged token or a 2-legged token with user-impersonation can be used for uploading files to ACC or BIM360.

For automation, create a robot user account.  This user will appear in the activity feed for audits.
Then, use either a 3-legged refresh token server, or use a 2-legged token with `x-user-id`.   In either case, you will need to specify some kind of user identity.

**Details**
When you upload a file, the UI and audit system, needs to know who it came from.   Other collaborators, will see that the file originated from you (or your auth credentials) in the UI.

2-legged Auth, can do file uploads to BIM360/ACC, but only if the API has a special user-context... the `x-user-id`

This effectively acts like a 3-legged token, by moving the identity into the API header... ie. impersonating a user.

Here is an example upload API that supports user impersonation via the `x-user-id` field:
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-POST/#headers

and here is how to find the userID to impersonate, refer to this answer:
[Using the x-user-id in the c# forge package within the 2legged context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59247756/using-the-x-user-id-in-the-c-sharp-forge-package-within-the-2legged-context)

For the 2-legged approach, you will need to setup 2-legged BIM360 permissions with your clientID via the app integration settings or create an app on the App Store and add the app to your hub.